# How do I decrypt password using crypto hash and salt with my function in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, encryption, hash

I have a set of server side functions that 1.

1. Generates a random salt
2. Uses password and salt to create a hash
3. Invokes the second function to create hashed password that is returned

   ```
   var sha512 = function(password, salt){
       var hash = crypto.createHmac('sha512', salt); /** Hashing algorithm sha512 */
       hash.update(password);
       var value = hash.digest('hex');
       return {
           salt:salt,
           passwordHash:value
       };
   };


   //--------------Function to hash password
   function saltHashPassword(userpassword) {
       var salt = genRandomString(16); /** Gives us salt of length 16 */
       var passwordData = sha512(userpassword, salt);
       console.log('UserPassword = '+userpassword);
       console.log('Passwordhash = '+passwordData.passwordHash);
       console.log('\nSalt = '+passwordData.salt);
       return passwordData;
   }
   //----------------------
   // Function to generate salt
   var genRandomString = function(length){
       return crypto.randomBytes(Math.ceil(length/2))
           .toString('hex') /** convert to hexadecimal format */
           .slice(0,length);   /** return required number of characters */
   };
   ```

Whenever I get a username and password in the sign up page, I can call saltHashPassword(passwordinstring) and get a hash and a salt. I then save this to the user document in the mongoose schema.

**How do I decrypt when the user is trying to login?**

This is a method I'm currently writing in the User schema, user.js. I'm stuck with how get the salt stored for the email provided.

```
// this authenticates the user against the database
UserSchema.statics.authenticate = function(email, password, callback){
    User.findOne({email: email})
        .exec(function(error, user){
            if(error){
                return callback(error);
            }else if(!user){
                var err = new Error("User not found");
                err.status = 401;
                return callback(err);
            }
            // if we reach this part of the code, then there is a valid username
            // I could call sha512(password, salt) and get the hash and then
            // match the two calculated hashed passwords. But how do 
            // I query the salt within a mongo query?
            // every user has email, hashed_password, salt fields in its document

        });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to reinvent the wheel. You could use bcrypt which wouldn't need you to store salt separately.

But since you already started with this:

```
// this authenticates the user against the database
UserSchema.statics.authenticate = function(email, password, callback){
    User.findOne({email: email})
        .exec(function(error, user){
            if(error){
                return callback(error);
            }
            if(!user){
                var err = new Error("User not found");
                err.status = 401;
                return callback(err);
            }
            // if we reach this part of the code, then there is a valid username
            // I could call sha512(password, salt) and get the hash and then
            // match the two calculated hashed passwords. But how do 
            // I query the salt within a mongo query?
            // every user has email, hashed_password, salt fields in its document


            var salt = user.salt; // Because you said that User has salt, email, hashed_password

            // Do your password matching....
        });
};
```

Mongoose's find and findOne methods return either the error or the document. You already have error and user in your callback. You can access the properties by user.email, user.salt, etc.

You don't need any separate queries, since the User contains the salt.

Comment: are you saying I should do do this `let salt = user.salt;
            let givenPassObj = sha512(password, salt);
            if(givenPassObj.passwordHash===user.hashed_password){
                return callback(null, user);
            }else{
                return callback();
            }`

Comment: Yes. That should do it.

Comment: @McFiddlyWiddly No don't do that.  Hashing with SHA512 is not secure for passwords.  Use bcrypt like stated in the post, or if you really want to use SHA512, use it as the primitive for PBKDF2.

Comment: Yep, thats why I said "like stated in the post" ;) I addressed the OP.